# iPhone app on iPad: drawViewHierarchyInRect causes glitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

Running an iPhone app on iPad (iOS 8), using drawViewHierarchyInRect to take a snapshot and do a custom animation between two view controllers. It all runs fine on iPhones but when the app is on iPad (not a universal app, iPhone only) you can see a brief glimpse of a bad snapshot when the animation starts. Basically it seems to take a snapshot of the whole iPad screen, including the black edges, rather than just the simulated iPhone screen. The app also hides the status bar but you can see the status bar in the brief glimpse which means it's probably some kind of bug in iOS as the iPad always shows the status bar for iPhone apps at the top of the screen.

Here's the snapshot code;

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
[view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:update];
UIImage *snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Incidentally the flash also occurs when using Airplay to show the app on Apple TV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it seems drawViewHierarchyInRect is somehow rendering to the screen briefly in this situation... Replacing it with CALayer's renderInContext removes the glitch, but unfortunately was less performant on my iPhone so I added a check to make sure the iPad simulation was the only one that needed to do this (fortunately it's quick enough on the iPad)

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
if( [self iPadRunningiPhoneSize] )
{
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
}
else
{
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:update];
}
UIImage *snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

And the function to check the situation where it's an iPhone app being 'simulated' on the iPad in case the app later goes universal

```
- (BOOL)iPadRunningiPhoneSize
{
    int name[] = {CTL_HW,HW_MACHINE};
    size_t size = 100;
    sysctl(name, 2, NULL, &size, NULL, 0); // getting size of answer
    char *hw_machine = malloc(size);

    sysctl(name, 2, hw_machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *hardware = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:hw_machine];
    free(hw_machine);

    int greaterBound = MAX( [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height );

    return [hardware rangeOfString: @"iPad"].location != NSNotFound && greaterBound == 480;
}
```

When using the iPad to Airplay to the Apple TV the glitch is fixed but of course the checking for an iPad simulating the iPhone app means that iPhones using Airplay still exhibit the glitch on the TV, but that's not a great concern for this app!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with below,

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, 0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *im = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Yes, CMash. But my opinion is, just add these lines irrespective to the device. Because this will work for both iPad n iPhone. So no need for check.

Comment: The layer renderInContext function is much poorer performance so causes lags

Comment: Yes, I read some where same about it. This is also reported to Apple. Apple only suggested the above solution.